# Sort a store data based on inner JSON field sencha

Tags: json, sorting, extjs, model, store

i have a json in the following format:

```
{
 "collection": [
 {
  "id": 4, 
  "tickets": [
      {
        "price": 40,
      },
      {
        "price": 50,
      }
    ],
  },
  {
  "id": 1, 
  "tickets": [
      {
        "price": 10,
      },
      {
        "price": 15,
      }
    ]
  },
 ]
}
```

STORE:

```
Ext.define("myProject.store.ABCs", {
extend: "Ext.data.Store",
config: {
    model: "myProject.model.ABC",
    autoLoad: false,            
    proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        url: '',  //myURL
        reader: {
            type: "json",
            rootProperty: "collection",   // this is the first collection
        },
    },

 }
});
```

For this particular JSON i created the models as:

```
Ext.define("myProject.model.ABC", {
extend: "Ext.data.Model",
config: {
    idProperty: "id",
    fields:[
        {name: "id", type: "int" },
    ],
    hasMany: [
        {
            model: "myProject.model.XYZ",
            name: "tickets",
            associationKey: "tickets",
        },
    ],
  }
});
```

And second model as:

```
Ext.define("myProject.model.XYZ", {
extend: "Ext.data.Model",
config: {
    // idProperty: "id",
    fields:[
     {name: "inner_id", type: "int" },

    ],
     belongsTo: 'myProject.model.ABC'
 }
});
```

This particular code creates a store and populates the models correctly.

```
var store = Ext.getStore('ABCs');
```

Now i want to sort this store based on store.tickets().getAt(0).get('price')  that is sort the ABC records based on XYZ's first price property.

In the above json. ABC Records will be: [{id:4}, {id:1}] 
But since first price in XYZ (40 > 10), i want to sort them and create [{id:1}, {id:4}]

Comment: Is this Ext JS or Sencha Touch? What version?

Comment: It is sencha touch. Version 2.3

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Ext.util.Sorter](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Sorter) class, where you can set a *sorterFn*. See the example at the top of the page - you should be able to simply write the logic for sorting records the way you describe.